# Error in Oracle BI expression

Tags: oracle, expression, business-intelligence, obiee, fusion

I am trying to check if the field is 0 or null and if so, the remaining amount will be equal the invoice amount.

This error appears and I searched for it but I found nothing!

[image]

Here is the code:

```
IF (G_Invoice.Amount_Paid = 0 OR G_Invoice.Amount_Paid is null )

then

Remaining_Amount := G_Invoice.Invoice_Amount

else

G_Invoice.Invoice_Amount-G_Invoice.Amount_Paid

end if;
```

Comment: Have you tried a case statement (e.g. https://gerardnico.com/dat/obiee/obis/logical_sql/case)?

Comment: The THEN part contains an ASSIGNMENT, that is correct. The ELSE part does not - it is just an arithmetic expression. You are missing `Remaining_Amount :=` in that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the measure is being calculated in Oracle BI, the LSQL code should be:

```
Remaining_Amount - ifnull(G_Invoice.Amount_Paid,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is easy to explain (I did so in a brief Comment).

But the same result may be obtained much more simply:

```
Remaining_Amount := G_Invoice.Invoice_Amount-NVL(G_Invoice.Amount_Paid, 0)
```

No need for an IF statement (that is hidden within NVL). No need to treat the case of the paid amount being zero as a special case (if you subtract 0, that is the same as returning the INVOICE_AMOUNT unchanged). NVL will cause a `null` to be converted to zero.